Do non-constant aperture zoom lenses vary aperture when zooming, when the aperture is not set to wide-open?
I am an experienced amateur photographer and videographer using a Sony a7sII with a Sigma 28-300mm f3.5-6.3 hyperzoom lens for a music video shot. I notice that when I test the shot zooming out all the way from 300mm to 28mm on this lens, the aperture changes from f11 to f6.3 by the time it reaches 28mm. I have ensured that I am in manual exposure mode.
Is this normal? I understand that zoom lenses have variable apertures but I did not think that this meant you cannot have a constant aperture when zooming in if it above the minimum aperture for any given focal length across the available range.

I have a 120-400 Sigma zoom and the aperture remains constant when I zoom in and out, provided it is within the aperture range of the focal length (so  f/11 the aperture doesn't change over the hole zoom range). Have you checked if Sigma states the compatibility of uour camera model with your lens?

What specific Sigma 28-300mm lens is this? I don't think has made any 28-300mm f/35-6.3 in Sony E-Mount. So what specific adapter are you also using with it?

This is likely the Sigma 28-300mm f/3.5-6.3 DG introduced in 2002 in Nikon F, Canon EF, Minolta A, Pentax, and Sigma mounts. To use it with a Sony E-Mount camera some sort of adapter is involved, whether mechanical only or mechanical + electronic. This question is impossible to properly answer until we know the specific lens model, the specific mount, and the specific adapter being used.

Try setting your ISO to float (auto) and manually set your aperture and speed.  When you zoom, your ISO will course correct in one-third stops... and is not noticeable.

That does not seem normal to me...
What it is doing is holding the physical aperture size constant as you change the zoom... rather than the f#. That's what will normally happen if you start at 28mm f/3.5 and change the zoom; because it can't maintain the f#... but in manual or aperture priority it should maintain the f# if possible.
Maybe try aperture priority to see if it behaves the same.

This is a film era lens and has never been made in Sony E-mount. We need to know what specific lens this is, in what specific mount, being used with what specific adapter before we can do anything besides shooting in the dark.
